# Deadlock In Sql Server 2012 With Merge

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We have a complicated publishing model in our application that allows different users to see different objects.  We generate which users can see which objects as the view which determines this is quite slow.  We have a background service that runs every 10 minutes which uses a merge statement to ensure the stored table is up to date, we also have merge statement that runs per user at the beginning of a request.  Very rarely we are getting a deadlock situation when the merge runs for a user at the same time as the merge runs for the whole database and an update exists.  Is there a way to stop this happening as I would expect one to complete and then release the locks and then the next complete, find no data to update and continue.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="processe7058f0c8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="processe7058f0c8" taskpriority="0" logused="344" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057600589430784 (dc897b8904f5)" waittime="1341" ownerId="62095831" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-02-06T16:29:17.037" XDES="0xe789ce3a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="4072" status="suspended" spid="59" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-06T16:29:17.037" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-06T16:29:17.033" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.033" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ZNPRODWEB1" hostpid="22512" loginname="DATABASE" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="62095831" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="DATABASE.Store.UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersForUsers" line="20" stmtstart="794" stmtend="3468" sqlhandle="0x03000700d8b7073ae34ef00037a4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
MERGE [Store].StoredPublishingSegmentUsers AS TARGET
      USING 
      (
          SELECT realTimePublishings.PublishingSegmentId, 
                 realTimePublishings.UserId, 
                 realTimePublishings.IsParticipating,
                 realTimePublishings.IsVisibleWithFilter
            FROM Publishing.PublishingSegmentUsersRealTimeData realTimePublishings
           INNER JOIN @UserIds u ON u.Id = realTimePublishings.UserId
      ) AS SOURCE
      ON TARGET.PublishingSegments_PublishingSegmentId = SOURCE.PublishingSegmentId 
      AND TARGET.Users_UserId = SOURCE.UserId 
      WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.IsParticipating != SOURCE.IsParticipating) 
                    OR (TARGET.IsVisibleWithFilter != SOURCE.IsVisibleWithFilter) THEN
        UPDATE SET TARGET.IsParticipating = SOURCE.IsParticipating,
                   TARGET.IsVisibleWithFilter = SOURCE.IsVisibleWithFilter
      WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([PublishingSegments_PublishingSegmentId], [Users_UserId    </frame>
        <frame procname="DATABASE.Store.ProcessStoreUpdatesForCustomer" line="51" stmtstart="2844" stmtend="3082" sqlhandle="0x030007008e48614a974ff00037a4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC Store.UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersForUsers @UserIds

         -- Update the stored incentive program leagues    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1247889550]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="processe7f0450c8" taskpriority="0" logused="352" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:42475 " waittime="1272" ownerId="62094952" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-02-06T16:29:15.450" XDES="0xe6e6c63a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="7" kpid="1260" status="suspended" spid="67" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-06T16:29:15.450" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-06T16:29:10.670" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.670" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ZNPRODWEB1" hostpid="19952" loginname="DATABASE" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="62094952" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="DATABASE.Store.UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersForUsers" line="20" stmtstart="794" stmtend="3468" sqlhandle="0x03000700d8b7073ae34ef00037a4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
MERGE [Store].StoredPublishingSegmentUsers AS TARGET
      USING 
      (
          SELECT realTimePublishings.PublishingSegmentId, 
                 realTimePublishings.UserId, 
                 realTimePublishings.IsParticipating,
                 realTimePublishings.IsVisibleWithFilter
            FROM Publishing.PublishingSegmentUsersRealTimeData realTimePublishings
           INNER JOIN @UserIds u ON u.Id = realTimePublishings.UserId
      ) AS SOURCE
      ON TARGET.PublishingSegments_PublishingSegmentId = SOURCE.PublishingSegmentId 
      AND TARGET.Users_UserId = SOURCE.UserId 
      WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.IsParticipating != SOURCE.IsParticipating) 
                    OR (TARGET.IsVisibleWithFilter != SOURCE.IsVisibleWithFilter) THEN
        UPDATE SET TARGET.IsParticipating = SOURCE.IsParticipating,
                   TARGET.IsVisibleWithFilter = SOURCE.IsVisibleWithFilter
      WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([PublishingSegments_PublishingSegmentId], [Users_UserId    </frame>
        <frame procname="DATABASE.Store.UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersForUser" line="9" stmtstart="352" stmtend="484" sqlhandle="0x0300070011dcfb3af84ef00037a4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC Store.UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersForUsers @UserIds;    </frame>
        <frame procname="DATABASE.Store.ProcessStoreUpdatesForUser" line="35" stmtstart="1814" stmtend="2048" sqlhandle="0x03000700832bce510e50f00037a4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC Store.UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersForUser @UserId

         -- Update the stored incentive program leagues    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1372466051]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057600589430784" dbid="7" objectname="DATABASE.Store.StoredPublishingSegmentUsers" indexname="PK_StoredPublishingSegmentUsers" id="locke68752b80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057600589430784">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processe7f0450c8" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processe7058f0c8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="42475" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="DATABASE.Store.StoredPublishingSegmentUsers" id="locke64335280" mode="IU" associatedObjectId="72057600589430784">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processe7058f0c8" mode="IU" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processe7f0450c8" mode="U" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Take a look at this question and answers here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/sql-server-2008-merge-statement-deadlocking-itself - perhaps you could use sp_getapplock to serialize the merge operations.

Comment: IMHO,I think before using any lock mechanism.First thoroughly draw and check the sequence of event on paper.Deadlock also occur when events are not in  sequence .If I understood properly,may be you should add one column bit type(default 0).One event will update it to 1 then only second event can process further.Hope you got my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a hard to solve deadlock. Usually, one would solve this by ensuring a consistent lock order and increasing the lock mode to something above `S`. It is unclear how this would be done here.

Suggestions:

1. Can you tolerate the (rare) background update to U-lock the table? That would allow reads to happen concurrently but it would lock out all other updates. Use: `WITH (TABLOCK, UPDLOCK)`.
2. Set `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` to `LOW` for the rare background update and put it in a retry loop. Retries are a valid way to solve deadlock problems.
3. The deadlock is due to one tran locking rows, the other locking pages. You *might* be able to solve this by making both statements use `ROWLOCK`. I'm not experienced at doing this so this is just a guess.

All three should cause minimal code changes.

I'd probably favor (2) because it is easy to understand, simple and clearly correct.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I decided to go with option 2 and it seems to be the easiest way to handle this.  We are now gracefully allowing the background service to fail and retry with a low deadlock priority.